# Trying to restrict pages to only users who are logged in but conditional never seems to run

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to set up routing in React v18 that restricts certain pages to only users who are logged in. I can't seem to get the function in the `return` statement to work. `Login` and `Register` work OK. If I put another component outside the function, the same level as `Login` and `Register`, it works fine, too. But when the page loads, it should got to `localhost/`, see there's no token, then route to `/login`. Right now it just stays on `localhost/` and shows an empty page. The warning in the console says "No routes match location '/' ". That is true, because the component with path "/" is in `AppViews` and should be restricted. But it's not moving the user to `/login'. Why not? What am I missing?

```
export const MyApp = () => {
  const [token, setTokenState] = useState(localStorage.getItem('token'))

  const setToken = (newToken) => {
    localStorage.setItem('token', newToken)
    setTokenState(newToken)
  }


  return (
    <>
        <Routes>
            { <Route render={() => {
                if (localStorage.getItem("app_token")) {
                    return <>
                        <Route>
                            <AppViews />
                        </Route>
                    </>
                } else {
                    return <Navigate to="/login" />
                }
                }} />
             }
            <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
            <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />         
        </Routes>
    </>
  )
}
 
export default MyApp;
```

Comment: Your `Route` that contains the logic is wrapped in a JSX expression `{ }`. I've honestly never seen that before, but I don't think it will render using that syntax. Try removing the `{ }` and see if that solves it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `react-router-dom@6` the `Route` component hasn't any `render` prop. In other words, the `render` prop is completely ignored and has no effect. All the routed content is rendered out on the `element` prop. Use a ternary operator to conditionally render the redirect or the `AppViews` component.

```
export const MyApp = () => {
  const [token, setTokenState] = useState(localStorage.getItem('token'))

  const setToken = (newToken) => {
    localStorage.setItem('token', newToken)
    setTokenState(newToken)
  }

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route
        path="/*"
        element={localStorage.getItem("app_token")
          ? <AppViews />
          : <Navigate to="/login" replace />
        }
      />
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
      <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />         
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

It's more conventional to create a protected route component.

Example:

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const ProtectedRoute = () => {
  const appToken = localStorage.getItem("app_token");

  return appToken
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to="/login" replace />
};
```

...

```
export const MyApp = () => {
  const [token, setTokenState] = useState(localStorage.getItem('token'))

  const setToken = (newToken) => {
    localStorage.setItem('token', newToken)
    setTokenState(newToken)
  }

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route element={<ProtectedRoute />}>
        <Route path="/*" element={<AppViews />} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
      <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />         
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

Comment: This almost works. When routed to <AppViews />, the element doesn't load, however. I just get an empty screen.

export const AppViews= () => {
        return (
        <>
            <Routes>
                <Route exact path="/" element={ <Cars /> } />
            </Routes>
        </>
        )
}

Comment: @CodeMonkey I see, so `AppViews` is rendering descendent routes? Add the wildcard `"*"` to the end of that route's path, i.e. `<Route path="/*" element={<AppViews />} />` so the descendent routes can also be matched and returned/rendered.